# introduce a c script in a bash file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, c

My problem is to recover data keyed in text file in bash. I seek the command that can perform this task and I used `sed`, `awk` and even `cut` but I have not succeeded. One friend of mine suggested to introduce a C program that performs this task.

Can I introduce in a bash file the C program. If I can, how? Or is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do in more detail, it is not very clear. Also show what you tried and why it didn't work - this will help us understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C program (it is not called a script or a code) has to be compiled, and although you can do so from a `bash` script, that assumes you have a compiler installed and other necessities.

Linux/Unix comes with many commands/programs, like `sed`, `awk` and `cut` that you mention,  that (in combination) can handle the larger part of processing text.

If your task requires some complex programming, e.g. a non-standard compression algorithm that has text as input and output, you might have to use a dedicated program instead of a combination of standard commands. In that case you should consider using Python/Perl/Ruby over writing a C program.

Comment: the problem is how to recover data entered by the user in a text file with bash script how can i do?

Comment: when the user entered data, I want these data will be stored in a text file. Expl: echo (" write your name please") i want that the name while be stored in a text file

Comment: @AomineDaiki This doesn't make sense at all. Why would need `awk`, `sed` or  a program for that? In bash you can do `read -p "Give your name: " name` and then do `echo "$name" > some_file` to that effect. You should update your question to make it more clear, not comment on  comments.